# firebase + angularjs order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

i want want to sort/orderby my date coming from firebase. it is not working in the traditional way how angular is ordering is handling `ng-repeat ... | orderBy:'<value>'`, because the firebase is returning a object back and angular can sort only on an array.

```
app.service('ContestantsService', function ($firebaseArray, FIREBASE_URI) {
  var service = this;
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
  var contestants = $firebaseArray(ref);

  service.getContestants = function () {
    return contestants; // <= this one i want to sort bis the 'score'
  };
```

Somehow i cant the use the `.orderBy`by the angularfire api. Is there a way to get the data in a sorted way?

#### Update:

I have added the following:

```
...
contestants.sort(compare);
function compare(a, b) {
    return a.score < b.score;
};
...
```

but it ist not working, perhaps it's getting the data via callback?

Comment: "i cant the use the .orderByby the angularfire api" Why not? Any code?

Answer (score 1):

[According to AngularFire docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray), `firebaseArray` is a regular array. You can do all the things you can like a regular array. However, they did say:

> While using read attributes and methods like length and toString() will work great on this array, you should avoid directly manipulating the array. Methods like splice(), push(), pop(), shift(), unshift(), and reverse() will cause the local data to become out of sync with the server.

You might want to create a function in the controller that grabs this array, copies and sorts it there, since sorting is just UI logic, and has nothing to do with the underlying structure of the data.

Comment: thx @joseph-the-dreamer it's still not working. any ideas why?